# text divided in a paragraph

Tags: html, css, text-decorations

I tried to have my text in a black background paragraph divided with white lines. I succeeded with text-decoration underline; the only problem is it won't stretch to full width and it's not perfect for the last line. Is there another solution? thanks guys

this is how it should look

[image]

http://codepen.io/HendrikEng/pen/LkXjWo

HTML:

```
<h1 class="o-outline--black">Lorem Ipsum impsum psuspspspspsp</h1>
```

CSS:

```
.o-outline--black {
    width: 30%;
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0.15em 0.6em 0.15em 0.6em;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: underline;
 }
```

Comment: why do you initialize the width twice with different values?

Comment: ups that wasnt meant to be ...i just added the first to make the line break in the codepen, i fixed it .

Comment: Will the text always be the same, or can it vary?

Comment: sorry ..made a mess here...now its how it should look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a linear gradient to get the effect you're after:

```css
.o-outline--black {
  width: 30%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.15em 0.6em 0.15em 0.6em;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, transparent 35px, white 35px, white 40px);
}
```

```html
<h1 class="o-outline--black">Lorem Ipsum impsum psuspspspspsp</h1>
```

You can tweak the pixel values to position the lines exactly where you need.

Answer (score 0):

`display: inline;` may fix your problem. That way the Black BG will be only where the text is.

-EDIT-

To force break the text you can add `<br>` on the words you want. And to align in to the center `margin: auto`;

http://codepen.io/sandrina-p/pen/AXmoxJ

Comment: thanks sandrian.. i kinda figured thats the only way ...i guess there is no real solution to handle it like in the example images ?

Comment: why -1 to all the answers ? ._.

Comment: Probably because none of them do what the OP asked for

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this instead:

```
.o-outline--black {
/*width: 40%;*/
display: block;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding: 0.15em 0em;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  /*text-decoration: underline;*/
text-align:center;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

.line
{
  width:100%;
  border-bottom:15px solid #ffffff;
}

<h1 class="o-outline--black underline">
<div class="line">marken-und</div>
<div class="line">packungsdesign. seit</div>
<div class="line">1997.</div>
</h1>


 <h1 class="o-outline--black underline">marken-und<br>packungsdesign. seit<br>1997.</h1>
```

Comment: You may also want to adjust the line-height.

Comment: thanks @raphael75 , its close but the problem is the white lines dont use the full with ..i think they can only be where the text is ...

Comment: Just updated the post above. I think this is what you want. You can play with the padding, line-height, and width.

Comment: yes thats how it should look ..thanks a lot...but i guess there is no way to avoid multiple classes? since the content is dynamic its a bit complicated i guess

Comment: That's correct. If you have a back-end technology on your server like PHP, you might be able to use it to make this more dynamic by writing the text in a loop, but otherwise it will likely need to be hardcoded.